# Is it possible to have a ctrl+click able link to a file with relative path in the comment

Tags: c#, visual-studio, relative-path, xml-comments, file-uri

I need to link a file in a comment so that others can click it and the explorer opens the folder or the file opens
I need something like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Does something see file://$(SolutionDir)/SomeFolder/somefile.txt"
/// </summary>
public void MyMethod()
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following comment to do it.

```
/// <summary>
    /// This is a math function I found <see href="file:///test">HERE</see>
    /// </summary>
    public void MyMethod()
    { }
```

The rule is `file:///` + your relative file path.

This is my tested result:

[image]

Comment: as I said in the title i need a **relative** path not an absolute one.

Comment: I make the relative path example, you can have a look.

Comment: this still does not work. for me it opens the folder where the visual studio .exe is and not the solution file or project file. or if i have the folder at C: as you do in your example it starts form C:. This however does not help me because in don't know where others have the project saved. The path needs to start with a folder somewhere in the Project e.g. the folder where the solution file lies, the folder where the .cs file lies, the output folder, the bin folder. if the first folder is C: it is still an absolut path.